# Why it wont let me override addViewControllers method from WebMvcConfigurer interface?

Tags: spring-boot

Context:

1 - starting new Spring boot web app; 
2 - WebMvcConfig Class implementing WebMvcConfigurer interface

The code is copied from a previous Spring MVC project where it works.

STS suggests to delete the override annotation and deleting does make the error disappear but, my intention is to override the method and also, will it actually work without the override?

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xxxxxx.mwadmin")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/springdb");
        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping rmhm = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        rmhm.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(true);
        rmhm.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true);
        return rmhm;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");

    }

}
```

Problem:

On my config Class STS showing the error "The method addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry) of type WebMvcConfig must override a superclass method".

Comment: It works fine for me with spring boot `2.1.8.RELEASE`. Could you share the exact spring boot version and also the imports you're using?

Comment: `  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>`

Comment: version 2.2.0 and added the imports to the code

Comment: it does compile here! did you try to refresh/update the project within your IDE?

Comment: OK, i think this is an IDE issue. It seems STS is for some reason using Java 1.5 as default. I will need to work on that and i will come back with the result.

Comment: Confirmed! The problem was the Java version. For some reason STS is applying Java 1.5 by default to all new projects hence why it would not allow to use the annotation override in this implementation. Changed to 1.8 and it works fine.